# MOSFET GS resistor

Tags: mosfet

This figure show the MOSFET with GS resistor to prevent the MOSFET turn on, but I don't know why it would turn on.

1. Why MOSFET usually add the GS resistor about 4k~10k?
2. How to choose the resistor value?
3. What happen if we don't add resistor in there?

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116954/discussion-on-question-by-jason-mosfet-gs-resistor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gate-source is a capacitor whose voltage determines how much the MOSFET turns on. It doesn't discharge unless something discharges it. The resistor just makes sure it is well behaved when not being driven (like when there is no logic power) so it doesn't pick up a charge and turn on.

4k-10k aren't hard values. You could probably go 100k or even 1M if you wanted to. 4k-10k is just your typical pull-up value that works with many types of inputs and doesn't draw too much current.

Comment: can you said more detail? I still don't understant

Comment: @jasen Maybe you should read up on the gate-source capacitance.

Comment: can you use my figure to express what you mean,
I would like to know why the mosfet will turn on if we don't put the resisto, is because the Idg charge Cgs?

Comment: When you first connect the power supply to the transformer, current can flow through the capacitive divider formed by Cgd and Cgs in series and charge it up. There are other ways Cgs can get charged or stay charged though, like during power down of the 8342.

Answer (score 2):

Not having a gate-source resistor can lead to unwanted turn-on of the MOSFET or continued turn-on when the gate driver is not actively driving the gate to a defined potential anymore.

The size of the resistor is chosen by the tradeoff between fast turn-off in the absence of a defined gate driver signal and the additional power dissipation when the driver is supplying a gate-source voltage. Depending on the application and the MOSFET, either the driver power dissipation or the fast discharge of the gate capacitance are more important. A resistor in the lower kOhm range should be a good compromise in most applications.

Comment: why don't put the resistor in there would lead to unwanted turn-on of the mosfet

Comment: For example you could charge the gate capacitance just by ESD when touching the MOSFET. This could turn it on or damage it. A gate source resistor can help to prevent something like this.

Comment: @Jason a common scenario where the GS resistor is required is when the gate is driven by a microcontroller: a uC's gpios are typically configured as input (floating) by default. Thus, the mosfets's state is not defined. Once the uC has booted and the gpio is qn output, the resistor would no longer be required.